# Changing maxHeight of angular-gantt component has no effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gantt-chart

I'm using angular-gantt library and have some troubles with changing height dynamically. When I set new value of maxHeight attribute in controller, it has no effect on the view. I think, that such changes should be possible, because works in demo app ([Angular Gantt demo](https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/) - when clicking Layout->Height). Maybe am I missing something? Appreciate any clues.

Here is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-gantt.css" />
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-gantt.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['gantt']);
        myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$window', function($scope, $window){

          $scope.cutSomeHeight = function() {
            $scope.options.maxHeight -= 50;
          }

          $scope.options = {
            maxHeight: 500,
            data: [],
            viewScale: "1 month",
            columnWidth: 100
          }

          for (var i=0; i<100; i++){
            $scope.options.data.push({name: 'Task' + i, tasks: [{name: i, from: moment("2015-01-01","YYYY-MM-DD").add(i % 12, 'months'), to: moment("2015-06-01","YYYY-MM-DD").add(i % 12, 'months')}]})
          }
       }]);
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <button ng-click="cutSomeHeight()">Cut</button>
      <div gantt options="options"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it works fine when i put max-height attribute inside gantt's div. Apparently it had some trouble with binding that variable to gantt's scope, relying only on options attribute.

```
<div gantt options="options" max-height="options.maxHeight"></div>
```